# Remove Pandas rows that contain approximate string matches

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove rows from a Pandas dataframe that have the same value in column A and are an approximate match in column B (by edit distance). Ex:

| Index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 'Apple' | 'bicycle' |
| 1 | 'Apple' | 'gigantic bicycle' |
| 2 | 'Apple' | 'a bicycle' |
| 3 | 'Peach' | 'bicycle' |
| 4 | 'Apple' | '~bicycle**' |
| 5 | 'Peach' | 'airplane' |
| 6 | 'Apple' | 'car' |
| 7 | 'Apple' | 'cars' |

In this case I want the resulting data frame to be:

| Index | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 'Apple' | 'bicycle' |
| 1 | 'Apple' | 'gigantic bicycle' |
| 3 | 'Peach' | 'bicycle' |
| 5 | 'Peach' | 'airplane' |
| 6 | 'Apple' | 'car' |

Rows 0 and 3 both remain because the value in column A is different, and row 1 remains because 'gigantic bicycle' is different enough from 'bicycle'. We want to remove matches closer than say an edit distance of 3.

I found the get_close_matches() in the difflib library has a decent matching system but doesn't seem to compare by edit distance so it's not quite what I need.

Comment: What kind of [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)?

Comment: Look at fuzzywuzzy package.

Comment: I was looking for and LCS edit distance (no substitution) but I found a solution using Levenshtein which I think is also fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into using Levenshtein distance. I believe there is a Python library for calculating this.

https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/

Comment: Thanks! I was able to solve using this library and iterrows(). I saved the lev dist as a new column then filtered based on that value

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what type of edit distance you're talking about, but fuzzywuzzy might have some functions that could help you. Personally I found [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/string-matching-with-fuzzywuzzy-e982c61f8a84) to be pretty helpful in understanding the different distance functions fuzzywuzzy has.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it would work, but I solved it using the python-Levenshtein package in sloth's answer